# RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY throws exception

Tags: java, exception, number-formatting, bigdecimal

I wrote this to test `BigDecimal` in action but found that `RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY` threw an exception. Can anyone explain why?

```
public class TestRounding2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Locale swedish = new Locale("sv", "SE");
        BigDecimal pp; //declare variable pp=pounds pence

        NumberFormat swedishFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(swedish);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER POUNDS AND PENCE TO AT LEAST FIVE DECIMAL PLACES :");

        pp = scan.nextBigDecimal();

        BigDecimal pp1 = pp.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        System.out.println("HALF_EVEN: £ " + pp1.toString());
        System.out.println(swedishFormat.format(pp1));

        BigDecimal pp2 = pp.setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        System.out.println("FLOOR: £ " + pp2.toString());
        System.out.println(swedishFormat.format(pp2));

        BigDecimal pp3 = pp.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);
        System.out.println("CEILING £: " + pp3.toString());
        System.out.println(swedishFormat.format(pp3));

        BigDecimal pp4 = pp.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
        System.out.println("HALF DOWN £: " + pp4.toString());
        System.out.println(swedishFormat.format(pp4));

        BigDecimal pp5 = pp.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("HALF UP: £ " + pp5.toString());
        System.out.println(swedishFormat.format(pp5));

        BigDecimal pp6 = pp.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP);
        System.out.println("UP: £ " + pp6.toString());
        System.out.println(swedishFormat.format(pp6));

        BigDecimal pp7 = pp.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
        System.out.println("DOWN: £ " + pp7.toString());
        System.out.println(swedishFormat.format(pp7));

        BigDecimal pp8 = pp.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP);
        System.out.println("UP:  " + pp8.toString());
        System.out.println(swedishFormat.format(pp8));

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post (add to your question) all exceptions that you're getting with full stack trace.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's by design. See javadoc:

> Rounding mode to assert that the requested operation has an exact
>            result, hence no rounding is necessary.  If this rounding mode is
>            specified on an operation that yields an inexact result, an
>            {@code ArithmeticException} is thrown.

This mode is made to specifically throw an exception if there is something to round.

Examples. Next code doesn't throw Exception.

```
    BigDecimal pp = new BigDecimal(7);
    pp.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);
    System.out.println(pp);
```

changing `7` to fractional number leads to an exception because it's now NECESSARY to round it:

```
    BigDecimal pp = new BigDecimal(7.1);
    pp.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);
    // java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary
    System.out.println(pp);
```

Comment: Need to update to `pp.setScale(1, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);` so it will throw exception

Comment: why is there an unnecessary mode to rounding , if it is necessary ?

Comment: @TheGreatGatsbo, I think it was added for the sake of completeness. So all paths in rounding code are covered by the corresponding modes.